# Como reconhecer e alterar o encoding de caracteres latinos no R?

Tags: r, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, iso-8859-1, web-scraping

Há algum modo eficiente de reconhecer o encoding de textos baixados da internet? Fiz um scraping de um site qualquer (ver código abaixo) e não consigo encontrar o encoding correto.

Na tag META do código fonte a especificação é "iso-8859-1" (latin1). Mas quando especifico essa configuração, continua não dando certo...

```
library(XML); library(httr)
url = "http://www.encontroabcp2014.cienciapolitica.org.br/site/anaiscomplementares?AREA=8"
site_gt = content(GET(url))
resumos_gt = xpathSApply(site_gt,'//div[@style="display:none;"]', xmlValue)
resumos_gt[1]
```

Nesse resultado, obtenho algo como: `"Estudos Legislativo no Brasil tÃƒÂªm concentrado suas pesquisas nos ÃƒÂ¢mbito federal e estadual"`. Como fazer `tÃƒÂªm` se transformar em `também`e `ÃƒÂ¢mbito` se transformar em `âmbito`?

Tentei tudo o que me veio à cabeça. E nada funcionou:

```
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="UTF-8", to = "latin1")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="UTF-8", to = "latin2")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="UTF-8", to = "iso-8859-15")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="UTF-8", to = "latin1//TRANSLIT")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="UTF-8", to = "latin2//TRANSLIT")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="UTF-8", to = "iso-8859-15//TRANSLIT")


    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="latin1", to = "UTF-8")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="latin2", to = "UTF-8")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="iso-8859-15", to = "UTF-8")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="latin1", to = "UTF-8//TRANSLIT")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="latin2", to = "UTF-8//TRANSLIT")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="iso-8859-15", to = "UTF-8//TRANSLIT")

    ####

    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="latin1", to = "ASCII")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="latin2", to = "ASCII")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="iso-8859-15", to = "ASCII")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="latin1", to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="latin2", to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="iso-8859-15", to = "ASCII")

    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="ASCII", to = "latin1")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="ASCII", to = "latin2")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="ASCII", to = "iso-8859-15")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="ASCII", to = "latin1//TRANSLIT")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="ASCII", to = "latin2//TRANSLIT")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="ASCII", to = "iso-8859-15//TRANSLIT")

    ####

    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="UTF-8", to = "ASCII")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="UTF-8", to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT")

    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="ASCII", to = "UTF-8")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="ASCII", to = "UTF-8//TRANSLIT")


    ####

    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="latin1", to = "latin2")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="latin1", to = "iso-8859-15")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="latin1", to = "latin2//TRANSLIT")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="latin1", to = "iso-8859-15//TRANSLIT")

    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="latin2", to = "latin1")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="latin2", to = "iso-8859-15")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="latin2", to = "latin1//TRANSLIT")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="latin2", to = "iso-8859-15//TRANSLIT")

    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="iso-8859-15", to = "latin1")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="iso-8859-15", to = "latin2")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="iso-8859-15", to = "latin1//TRANSLIT")
    iconv(resumos_gt[1], from="iso-8859-15", to = "latin2//TRANSLIT")
```

Estou usando um R 3.2.5 em um Windows 7 (e sim... tenho que manter esse sistema operacional. Aparentemente, no linux esse problema não ocorre -- ou é mais fácil de resolver).

Comment: Só um detalhe: `tÃƒÂªm` é `têm`, e não `também`. Se fosse `também` você veria as letras `t a m b  m` normalmente.

Comment: Seu exemplo não rodou aqui: `Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "c('xml_document', 'xml_node')"`.

Comment: De fato, @Molx... `tÃƒÂªm` é `tem`... hehe. Mas eu não consegui reproduzir esse erro que você encontrou com o `xpathSApply` . A princípio, a função `content` do pacote httr retorna um objeto que pode ser lido pela função `xpathSApply` do pacote XML.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
library(XML); library(httr)

url = "http://www.encontroabcp2014.cienciapolitica.org.br/site/anaiscomplementares?AREA=8"

site_gt =  GET(url)

site_gt = content(site_gt, as = "text")

site_gt <- htmlParse(site_gt, encoding = "UTF-8")

resumos_gt = xpathSApply(site,'//div[@style="display:none;"]', xmlValue)

resumos_gt
```

Solução foi primeiro ler o conteúdo da página como texto, e só depois aplicar o htmlParse com encoding UTF-8

Comment: Obrigado @Denisson Silva. Deu certo aqui. Uma observação: no seu código, está faltando especificar o que é o objeto `url`

Comment: Não ha de que @RogerioJB. Já incluir a especificação da url.

Answer (score 0):

As vezes, o texto pode conter mais de uma língua, apresentando "mais de um encoding" como exemplo a seguir, você pode verificar com a função

```
stringi::stri_enc_detect(as.character(msg$body))

Encoding      Language Confidence
UTF-8                     1.00
ISO-8859-1       pt       0.49
ISO-8859-2       ro       0.28
UTF-16BE                  0.10
UTF-16LE                  0.10
ISO-8859-9       tr       0.10
Shift_JIS        ja       0.10
GB18030          zh       0.10
EUC-JP           ja       0.10
EUC-KR           ko       0.10
Big5             zh       0.10
```

no meu caso resolvi assumir que o encoding primário era 'UTF-8', e o secundário também era 'UTF-8', de certo no meu caso.

```
iconv(as.character(msg$body), from = "UTF-8", to = "UTF-8")
```